# Moving triangle along median of another triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, triangles, transformation

For **any given triangle and x value** if I keep translating the two purple vectors down along the median, will they eventually both intersect A and B at the same time?
[image: diagram]

Comment: Let third vertex is C and middle of AB is D. Let move origin of purple vectors in direction DC. Then let find position of origin C$_1$ when left purple vector will point to A direction (but end of this vector is not A in this moment) and let find position of origin C$_2$ when right purple vector will point to B direction. Question is if C$_1$ and C$_2$ is the same point. Is it correct?

Comment: In order to show this fact, one can consider similar triangles DE$_1$C and DAC$_1$, where E$_1$ are initial position of end of left purple vector. And the same for right purple vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , provided that their velocity are same . It is because ; both the displacement vectors are same .